# Multiple selection lost when displaying ContextMenu

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, selection, multipleselection

When using multiple selection in a `TableView`, clicking with the secondary button on a selected row to use the `ContextMenu` of the table will deselect any selected rows except the one that has been clicked. Why does this happen? What is the point of multiple selection if you can't choose an option in the context menu that can apply to that selection?

I'm thinking this might be a bug. This is because in some cases when I select more than one row in my example below, the selection is retained. I couldn't figure out any pattern for when the selection is retained, it seems to happen stochastically.

**Update:** 
The comments have pointed out that this behaviour isn't stochastic. If you click on a part of the row that isn't a real column, the selection is lost. To me, this behaviour doesn't feel intuitive.

The following is an MCVE of a basic `TableView` that allows multiple selection.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestMultipleSelection extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Table
        TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // Column
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>("Column");
        col.setCellValueFactory(e -> new SimpleStringProperty(e.getValue().get(0)));
        table.getColumns().add(col);

        // Data
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList("One"), FXCollections.observableArrayList("Two"), FXCollections.observableArrayList("Three"));
        table.setItems(items);

        // ContextMenu
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Item1");
        contextMenu.getItems().add(item1);

        table.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Tested platforms:

- `Windows 8.1 Enterprise, 64-bit; Java 8u92.`
- `Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, 64-bit; Java 8u92.`

Comment: this only happens if you use the secondary click outside of a column.

Comment: Didn't notice this. I still think the selection should be kept regardless on where in the row the click occurs. But I'm editing my question. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It also happens if you click a row that isn't selected: though this behavior seems fairly intuitive (to me, anyway). Clicking on blank space to the right of the columns in a selected row is less intuitive; I guess one workaround would just be to ensure the columns fill the horizontal space allocated to the table.

Comment: The first behaviour you are describing does seem intuitive to me as well. I just forgot to say that the issue is limited to when one of the selected rows is clicked. Edited the question with that information. I guess I'll use your workaround. But an additional change that needs to be done for the workaround to look decent is to left align the column header, since the row column text is currently left aligned while the column header text i centered by default.